# Populate twig template from external api

Tags: symfony, templates, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am building a Drupal 8 site and am new to the twig templating engine. For one specific content type I would like to make a call to an external restful api and render some of the returned data as fields in the twig template.

I have an internal id to call out to the API and I would like to embed in the template:

- The api call
- set a number of variables from the call
- render the result (with some logic if it does not exist)

Is this something that is easy to do with twig and drupal 8? 
As a secondary question, is this secure?

The alternative at this stage is to write small Drupal 8 module but as there is no user input on the page, just rendering from the returned api call, I thought it would be easier to have it all in one place.

Comment: Twig is just the template engine, it does not care where the data comes from. It is only responsible of the output... So if your question is if twig can do this, then yes.

Comment: Are you saying I can just dump a php call in the middle of a template? Is that secure? What would that actually look like?

Comment: If you want to do an API call from inside you will need to [extend twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) and create a function that retrieves the data from the `API`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7 it was possible, but a poor design, to put arbitrary PHP into the template. In Drupal 8 it was made hard to do intentionally. You should not attempt to execute arbitrary PHP in your Twig files or make remote API calls that late in the processing of a request.

You should call the API and gather the data *before* you reach twig. You should create a custom module that handles that API interaction and places the response in a field, block, or another structure for rendering in the appropriate context (often a custom block works well for things like this, but exactly which approach makes the most sense depends on your project). You should also keep in mind that any page requiring a remote API call is likely to be slow unless that API call is very simple and very very fast. The BigPipe module can help you address those kinds of speed issues, but involve an additional learning curve.

If you want the browser to handle the API call, you will want to create a div (or similar markup) to place the results, and attach the JavaScript to the structure and make the actual API call after most of the page load is complete.

As for security: it is as secure as you make it. Drupal will provide some help to avoid the most common security mistakes, but you can still do things that would make it insecure (like sharing data with an untrusted third party or assuming the response data is always safe).

Comment: I accept that it is not the best practice. In this particular case we control both the site and the API and we are retrieving at most 100 characters of content to populate a few fields. As there is no user interaction and so little content I would, in the past, have just inserted some PHP in a template to make the desired API call. It appears that is somewhat more locked down with twig and so I will probably follow your advice and create an module to do this work. It just seems like a lot of code for what will be quite small amount of content.